# what is solution for getting Ionic 4 storage token value in constructor function e.g setting token to http headers at run time?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using Axios library for Ajax request. I am having issue not getting token from ionic local storage. My Axios method is as follows

```
 import axios from 'axios';
 import { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';
 import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

 // Some interface here
 @Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class AxiosService {
 token;

 private axiosClient: AxiosInstance;
 private errorHandler: ErrorHandler;

  // HERE I initialize the ApiClient
  constructor(errorHandler: ErrorHandler, public storage: Storage) {
  this.errorHandler = errorHandler;
  this.storage.get('token').then((data) => this.token = data;);

  this.axiosClient = axios.create({
    // timeout: 3000,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token
    }
   });
  }
  // here all crud request methods
 }
```

But Here I am getting undefined Bearer undefided.
I need Solution getting ionic storage token value at axios creation time in constructor. 
You can give solution over http interceptor that is also similar this problem it also initialised in contractor.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data from the local storage like this:

```
let myItem = localStorage.getItem(key);
```

For ionic you can do it like this

```
this.storage.get(this.key).then(value => {
    this.user = JSON.parse(value);
});
```

Comment: localStorage.getItem('token') giving null value. I haven't used localStorage.getItem() method in ionic. I don't know it works in ionic storage or not. But currently this giving null, whether this.storage.get('token').then(val => console.log(val)) giving my token value. I having problem with ionic storage.

Comment: I know how to get ionic local storage value. Read again my question. Have you used http interceptor ever? Try to read again my question.   The issue I am getting it setting this token in axios.create() httpHeader at run time. If you need any other help related question you can ping me.